# Should I use event design when handling no-idempotent invocation?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm working on an air booking project.

The image below shows the domain model we develop so far.

[image]

We define a domain service (AirBookService) which encapsulates booking, ticketing and other operations. Our suppliers provides Remote-Procedure-Call api to handle these requests, so we implement the domain service by adding an anti-corruption-layer(we have multiple suppliers).

This solution works fine when dealing with imdenpotent rpc calls such as getting price. However, there are risks when dealing with non-imdenpotent rpc calls.

For example

```
public class TransactionalReservationHandlingServiceImpl .... {
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void modifyTraveler(String resId, String tktId, AirTravler traveler) {
         AirReservation res = reservationRepository.findBy(resId);
         res.modify(tktId, traveler);
         airBookService.modify(res, traveler);
         reservationRepository.store(res);
    }
}
```

I place airBookService.modify() behind res.modify(), so the rpc call could be avoided if  some local domain logic is broken. But what if the rpc call succeeds and local transaction fails? We have a disparity between traveler in our application and that in supplier's application.

Is it worth handling rpc calls and local modification in seperate transactions?

My concern is:

```
a) It will surely introduce some extra complexity if doing so. like messaging.
b) I don' have much experience in event handling.
c) The failure chances are very low even if we use rpc call in the transaction boundary, mostly caused by concurrency problem and contetion of AirReservation is relatively low in real world.
```

Below is my event attempt:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void modifyTraveler(String resId, String tktId, AirTravler traveler) {
         AirReservation res = reservationRepository.findBy(resId);
         ModifyTravelerEvent event = airBookService.modify(res, traveler);
         handlingEventRepository.store(event);
         events.notifyTravelerModified(event);// using messaging
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void modifyTraveler(String eventSequence) {
         ModifyTravelerEvent event = handlingEventRepository.of(eventSequence);
         AirReservation res = reservationRepository.findBy(resId);
         event.handle(res);
         reservationRepository.store(res);
         handlingEventRepository.store(event );
    }
```

The advantage is local modification is seperated from rpc calls. 
But this introduces:
1.Multiple resource management issue(datasource and messaging)
2.I have to create a lot of ad-hoc event for modify traveler, demand ticket and any other AirBookService operations.

I'm in a dilemma, not satisfied with current design but quite hesitate with the new event design.

Any idea is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you mix your local modification with your remote modification. You worry that if your local modification fails after your remote modification succeeds you cannot roll back your remote modification anymore. So unmixing your two modifcations is definitely the way to go.

The simplest way to do this would be to swap the lines airBookService.modify call and the reservationRepository.store call:

```
public class TransactionalReservationHandlingServiceImpl .... {
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void modifyTraveler(String resId, String tktId, AirTravler traveler) {
         // local modification
         AirReservation res = reservationRepository.findBy(resId);
         res.modify(tktId, traveler);
         reservationRepository.store(res); // <- remember this should not actually store anything until after the commit

         // remote modification
         airBookService.modify(res, traveler);
    }
}
```

Since your local modification is transactional it will only commit after a successful remote modification.  Any kind of local problems that could have occurred would probably already have occurred. Of course, there is still a minuscule chance that committing the transaction itself fails. Therefore to be truly transactional, you would have to be able to roll back your remote modification. Since, I take it, you are not able to do so, true transactionality is actually impossible. The above construct is therefore the safest possible way in terms of consistency to do a local and remote modifications at the same time, since the chance that the commit of the local modification itself fails is negligible. I say this, because even if you would introduce messaging there is still a similar slight chance that the message itself is not committed after the remote modification.

The above construct however does have one big issue: it would probably hamper performance pretty seriously (you don't want your transactions lingering too long). Messaging is therefore a very reasonable solution to this problem. It also has other advantages, like persistence, auditing and replaying of messages. Your messaging attempt therefore is quite legit in this respect. Your code however does seriously break the single responsibility rule since the messaging itself is mixed with the modification within the same method calls.

If you are concerned with too much boilerplate around messaging you should definitely check out akka.io. Spring JMS and ActiveMQ are also a pretty powerful combination if you are not looking for an entire paradigm shift, but just for a decent messaging solution. Using one of these two technologies I've suggested you can create a powerful framework for your local calls that are paired with remote calls that allows you to avoid a lot of boilerplate.

I hope this helps. Good luck!